# MST to UTC php issue

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

I convert MST server time to UTC like this:

```
$msttime="2012-09-15 17:00:01";
$getdatetimeUTC=gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($msttime));
```

and i get this:

2012-09-15 23:00:01

which is wrong!

Why is this happening? I should have gotten 2012-09-15 24:00:01.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug of php i used date_default_timezone_get() and gave me MDT although my server is MST. I had to configure the settings of php to make it work!.